# How to populate part with session data in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm trying to return a ContentPart from the HTTP session in a Driver. Here is the code for my Driver and ContentPart:

```
public class UnpersistedPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<UnpersistedPart>
{
    public Localizer T { get; set; }
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UnpersistedPartDriver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is responsible for displaying your part in the frontend.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="part">Your part.</param>
    /// <param name="displayType"></param>
    /// <param name="shapeHelper"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override DriverResult Display(UnpersistedPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.Current().Session;
        var cart = session["Cart"] as UnpersistedPart;
        if (cart == null) {
            cart = new UnpersistedPart();
            session["Cart"] = cart;
        }

        return ContentShape("Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted(ContentPart: part));
    }

    // There is nothing to edit and update, so we don't need Editor methods.
}
public class UnpersistedPart : ContentPart
{
    public UnpersistedPart()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
        this.Items.Add(new Item { Id = 1, Title = "Book 1", Price = "130.00", Quantity = "1" });
        this.Items.Add(new Item { Id = 2, Title = "Book 2", Price = "145.00", Quantity = "2" });
        this.Items.Add(new Item { Id = 3, Title = "Book 3", Price = "150.00", Quantity = "3" });
    }

    public IList<Item> Items;
    public string Total
    {
        get 
        {
            return Items.Sum(i => i.Total).ToString();
        }
    }
    public string SessionId;
}

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public int Id;
    public string Title;
    public string Price;
    public string Quantity;
    public decimal Total { get { return decimal.Parse(Price) * int.Parse(Quantity); } }
}
```

When I change part to cart:

```
return ContentShape("Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted(ContentPart: part));
```

to:

```
return ContentShape("Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted(ContentPart: cart));
```

it doesn't display anything. I get an empty article tag:

<article class="content-item book" shape-id="0"></article>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty tag usually means that there was some exception in the background. 
Please take a look in /App_Data/Logs.

I see what you want to achieve, but you should've done that differently.

**Best practice is to utilize `OnLoading` event of content handler to populate part properties with data from different sources, eg. session.** *Storing the whole part in session will surely run you into trouble at some point, especially when the part is bound to a database record.*

**Handlers** should perform all preparation operations.

**Drivers** should only hold display/editor-related logic on a ready-to-use part (like choosing the right shape, preparing the view model). So drivers should be kept very simple most of the time.

So in your case the steps would be:

1. **Create a CartHandler** class that derives from ContentHandler
2. **Use OnLoading event** in the handler created in 1. **to hydrate the property/ies** with data from session.

Example:

```
public class CartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public CartHandler(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        this.OnLoaded<UnpersistedPart>(ctx, part =>
        {
            var session = context.GetCurrent().Session;
            // Here comes loading data from session

            part.MyProperty = session["Something"]; 
            // ........ 
        });
    }
}
```

This event will get called every time a content item containing it will get loaded, before displaying it. So in the driver you will receive a fully populated part.

After adding a handler, your driver Display method would look way much simpler:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(UnpersistedPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return ContentShape("Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted",
        () => shapeHelper.Parts_Jumpstart_Unpersisted(ContentPart: part));
}
```

Comment: What Piotr say's is right, don't store the whole ContentPart in your session, it's much better to store just an identifier

Comment: Thanks for that. Are there any modules in the orchardcms that show this stuff. I can't find any documentation on the onloaded event.

Comment: Here is some info about handlers: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-content-handlers. This topic will give you a bit more insight on how everything works, although needs some more detailed info.